# C Morse code converter shows no error in compiler but doesn't work

Tags: c

I am trying to write a simple program that takes a string input and then converts it into morse code.

When I compile the code and run it, I get no errors but it sometimes gives an output, sometimes doesn't, sometimes gives only the half of it. I can kind of understand that the algorithm that I use right now can be a bit slow to convert a big string but it does the same behaviour for even one character.

So what is wrong about my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char characters[26]= {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
    char *morse[26] = {".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---","-.-",".-..","--"," -.","---",".--.","--.-",".-."," ...","-","..-","...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--.."};
    char input[25];
    char *output[25];
    gets(input);

    int i = 0, k = 0; //Make all of the chars uppercase to compare with the array.
    while(i < 25) {
        input[i] = toupper(input[i]);
        while(input[i] != characters[k]){
            k++;
        }
        output[i] = morse[k]; //Assign the according morse code to the output's pointers.
        i++;
    }

    int n = 0;
    while(n < 25){
        if (output[n] != NULL){  //Print out everything except empty parts
            printf("%s", output[n]);
            n++;
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Where do you initialize the unused elements of `output` to `NULL`?

Comment: The fact it compiles only means it is correct as far as syntax. It has nothing to do with whether the code is correct logically. Use a debugger to step through the code to see how its working differently than you intended.

Comment: Don't use `gets()`, it has no bounds checking and has been removed from the language. Use `fgets(stdin, input)`.

Comment: You should stop processing `input` when you get to the null terminator. If the user enters less than 25 characters you'll process uninitalized elements.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the previous comments, how can I stop processing the input part like you said? By using some kind of a function that gives the length of the input?

Comment: You forgot to reset `k`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some remarks :

- `while(i < 25)` must be `while(input[i] != 0)`
- you also need to reset *k* to 0 in `while(input[i] != 0)` (if using the associated loop)
- do not use *gets* but *fgets*
- you also need to change `while(n < 25)` by `while (n < i)`. Your `output[n] != NULL` is not a protection because *output* is not initialized to NULL, so you access to non initialized value with the associated undefined behavior
- you need to read only letter else `while(input[i] != characters[k])` will go out of *characters*. It is also expensive to search for the code through a loop, just use character code - 'A' to be an index

Finally a proposal :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    const char * const morse[] = {".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---","-.-",".-..","--"," -.","---",".--.","--.-",".-."," ...","-","..-","...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--.."};
    char input[25];
    const char *output[25];

    if (fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin) == NULL)
      return 0;

    int i = 0; //Make all of the chars uppercase to compare with the array.

    while((input[i] != 0) && isalpha(input[i])) {
      char c = toupper(input[i]);

      output[i++] = morse[c - 'A']; //Assign the according morse code to the output's pointers.
    }

    int n = 0;
    while (n < i)
      printf("%s", output[n++]);

    putchar('\n');

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -g -Wextra mo.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
SOS
 ...--- ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please explain how the -  'A' works also?

Comment: @Pearlescent I suppose you mean about `morse[c - 'A']`. Because of the check `isalpha(input[i])` then `char c = toupper(input[i]);` it is sure _c_ is a letter from 'A' to 'Z', so `c - 'A'` value between 0 and 25 and can be used as the index in _morse_. BTW I just see I forget to remove _characters_, I edit, and also add some _const_

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `k` back to zero every time you search `characters`. Since you don't do this, you start your search from the position that the last search ended. If the next character is earlier in the alphabet, you won't find it and the search will read outside the array.

Also, if any of the input characters aren't letters, the search will never find it. The loop has no check for this.

A simpler method would be to first check `isalpha()` to make sure that the input is a letter, and then calculate `input[i] - 'A'` and use that as the index into `morse`.

When processing `input` you should stop when you get to the null terminator, not go all the way to `i = 24`.

```
int i = 0;
while (input[i]) {
    if (isalpha(input[i])) {
        input[i] = toupper(input[i]);
        output[i] = morse[input[i] - 'A'];
    } else {
        output[i] = NULL;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use fgets to get input of variable length (just give it a character pointer)
Use strlen to get the length input to control your loop.
You might also want to reset the value of k when i is incremented so that you don't run out of bounds in the characters array.

Answer (score 0):

Barmar's comment above is correct. In addition to that, your program depends on the user entering a string that consists entirely of characters. What do you think will happen in your inner while loop if your string contains, say, a "1"?

Comment: I was thinking about fixing those problems later on. I am trying to produce the code that works firstly right now.

Comment: So, are you saying that the program fails when you give it exactly 25 alpha characters as input?